# compare coredata with string

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

in objective c i cant compare my coredata with a string

```
- (IBAction)loginBut:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDel managedObjectContext];
    /*NSEntityDescription *newPassword = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pinpass" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //[newPassword setValue:@"9090" forKey:@"password"];
    //[context save:nil];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Pinpass"];
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);*/
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Pinpass"];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(password = %@)", loginField.text];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; ;


    if (result.count > 0){

        //If([[textField text] compare:entity.attribute]==NSOrderedSame) NSLog(@"Correct!");
                if ([[loginField text] isEqual:[result valueForKey:@"password"]])
 {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign in ok"
                                                        message:@"Sign in succsess!!"
                                                        delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                        [alert show];
        }
        else{ UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign in ok"
                                                            message:@"Sign in succsess!!"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Say Hello",nil];  }

    }
```

is something wrong with my code?? or is just a bad use of functions

Comment: You need to describe in more detail what you are expecting and what you're seeing. Specifically which bit of code? Is the alert view code really relevant...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[loginField text] isEqual:[result valueForKey:@"password"]])
```

`result` is an array so you need to specify an index and then check the value at that index.

For example, the line above should be something like

```
if ([[loginField text] isEqual:[[result valueForKey:@"password"] lastObject]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here:

1. Your predicate is checking for managed object with the attribute `password` equal to `loginField.text`, so any match automatically is the correct password by definition.
2. Your `result` is a `NSArray`. Presumably you want to compare your textField text to a single object in that array. Something like this:

`if (result.count > 0) {
       firstResult = [result firstObject];
       if ([[loginField text] isEqual:[firstResult valueForKey:@"password"]]) {
        do stuff...
       }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Result array contains NSManagedObject name Pinpass. So you need to get the value from it and compare...

```
if (result.count > 0){
Pinpass *pinObj=[result objectAtIndex:0];

if ([[loginField text] isEqual:[pinObj valueForKey:@"password"]])
 {
 //AlertView
 }
 else
 { 
 //AlertView
 }

}
```

Hope it helps you..!